# Переклад терміна "device" українською мовою

Tags: переклад, from-english

При перекладі комп'ютерного терміна *"device"* зустрічала українські відповідники "девайс" та "пристрій".

Онлайн словник Glosbe перекладає термін [device](https://uk.glosbe.com/en/uk/device) таким чином.

Microsoft Language Portal подає наступний переклад терміна [device](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/language/Search?&searchTerm=device&langID=Ukrainian&Source=true&productid=All%20Products) та приклади його вживання у контексті.

Який переклад використовувати для кращого розуміння, зафіксований - **"пристрій"** чи все ж таки той, що набуває нового поширення - **"девайс"**?

Comment: Будь ласка, впишіть у запитання ті варіанти перекладу, які надаються за посиланнями, а також уточніть, чим са́ме вони не підходять, з вашої точки зору. Інакше, тривіальною відповіддю буде «ось, Майкрософт пропонує такий переклад, і це є відповідь на запитання».

Answer (score 5, accepted):

«Девайс» не належить до загальної лексики. Це є сленг/жаргон.

«Пристрій» — нейтральне слово (наприклад, [застосовується](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=195456&page=516) в означеннях «Словника української мови» в 20 томах).

«Девайс» прийнятний лише в окремих контекстах (наприклад, на IT-конференції в стилі «свої для своїх», де лексика фактично розмовна і навіть без цього слова насичена жаргоном/професіоналізмами), але не в діловому мовленні чи тесті загального призначення.