# Як українською перекладати склад журналу замовлення (product backlog items)?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Якщо поглянути в Azure DevOps на процеси ми побачимо наступні поняття. Як їх коректно перекласти Українською мовою?

1. Scrum

   - Epic – Epics help teams effectively manage and groom their product backlog
   - Feature – Tracks a feature that will be released with the product
   - Product Backlog Item – Tracks an activity the user will be able to perform with the product.
   - Bug – Describes a divergence between required and actual behavior, and tracks the work done to correct the defect and verify the correction.
   - Task – Tracks work that needs to be done.
   - Impediment – Tracks an obstacle to progress.
   - Test Case – Server-side data for a set of steps to be tested.
   - Test Plan – Tracks test activities for a specific milestone or release.
   - Test Suite – Tracks test activities for a specific feature, requirement, or user story.
2. Agile:

   - Epic – Epics help teams effectively manage and groom their product backlog
   - Feature – Tracks a feature that will be released with the product
   - User Story – Tracks an activity the user will be able to perform with the product
   - Bug – Describes a divergence between required and actual behavior, and tracks the work done to correct the defect and verify the correction.
   - Task – Tracks work that needs to be done.
   - Issue – Tracks an obstacle to progress.
   - Test Case – Server-side data for a set of steps to be tested.
   - Test Plan – Tracks test activities for a specific milestone or release.
   - Test Suite – Tracks test activities for a specific feature, requirement, or user story.

Однозначно легко перекласти:

- Task – задача
- Bug – дефект
- Feature – функціональна можливість (може якось коротше можна?)

Які є пропозиції щодо інших пунктів?

Comment: Це не перекладацький сайт, і замовлення щодо перекладу великих текстів є офф-топіком тут. Якщо вас цікавить переклад конкретного терміну (одного!), ви можете дослідити цю тему, поглянути, які переклади пропонують словники та/або професійні ресурси/компанії, потім визначити контекст (вам можуть відповідати не тільки фахівці I.T., і так і має бути, бо сайт про українську мову, а не про I.T.), потім пояснити, чим вас не подобаються запропоновані варіанти, і вже тоді очікувати на відповідь тут. Для запитання про ще один термін, вищеперелічене треба повторити і для нього у окремому запитанні

Comment: Приклади: [«Як перекласти українською "software framework"?»](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/746/8), [«Переклад терміна "device" українською мовою»](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/3670/8)

Comment: @bytebuster, згоден з вами загалом. Разом з тим, це набір зв'язаних загально прийнятих в ІТ-індустрії понять.
Я можу створити по питанню на кожне поняття, якщо поточна форма не відповідає правилам сайту.

Comment: Так, можете створити. Правила не обмежують вас у кількості запитань. І усі вони отримають свої заслуговані «плюси», якщо гарно підготовані. На практиці виявляється, що ретельно підготувати запитання потребує часу і зусиль, тому багато *якісних* запитань за короткий час просто не встигнете написати. :) Якщо запитання мають споріднений контекст абощо, можна у тексті вказати посилання на попередні запитання.